# When substituting with :%s/old/new/g, does g flag have any effect?

Tags: substitute

While working through vimtutor, I tried a variant on

```
:%s/old/new/g
```

by leaving off the `g` flag

```
:%s/old/new
```

and expected the substitution to only occur once in the whole file. After all, this mirrors the behavior of `:s/old/new`, which operates on the current line and only substitutes once unless the `g` flag is present.

However, the `g` the `:%s` substitution command does seem to matter, as both variants operate many times on the whole file. Is this documented anywhere, and how do you make sense of this discrepancy?

---

## Workaround

I'm aware that I can replace just one instance anywhere in the file with

```
:%s/old/new/gc
```

and decline the prompt after the first substitution. I'm seeking understanding on the non-interactive version without the `c` flag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `g` flag to the `:s` command does not influence how many items are replaced in the whole file, but rather how often to apply the substition **per line**. E.g. `:%s/foo/bar/g` in a file like this:

```
foo foo foo
foo
foo
```

it will be replaced to

```
bar bar bar
bar
bar
```

while the command `:%s/foo/bar/` will replace the file to:

```
bar foo foo
bar
bar
```

In general, if you want a region to be excluded from the effect of the `:s` command, you should use an address that excludes it from being affected by that command (this applies in general to all ex commands).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation @Christian Brabandt :)

Comment: @mksios And as always, the doc says it all: [`:h :s_flags`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3as_flags)